# Как сделать фон у Actor'а в LibGDX?

Tags: java, opengl, libgdx, background

В процессе изучения *LibGDX* возник вопрос: подскажите, пожалуйста, каким образом можно установить произвольному `Actor`'у цвет фона? Я имею в виду именно однотонную заливку, где все пиксели имеют одинаковое значение цвета/прозрачности. Впрочем, в дальнейшем наверняка понадобится ставить и картинку. Я нашла, как сделать заливку у `Label`'а:

```
testLabelStyle.background = testTextureRegionDrawable;
testLabel = new Label("Test!", testLabelStyle);
```

...однако этот метод, вероятно, имеется лишь у `Label`'а.

Comment: Заливку можно сделать простым одноцветным спрайтом и просто растянуть так как надо.

Answer (score 1):

Нужно сначала актеру дать какую-нибудь картинку

```
actorTexture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("actor.png"));
actorSprite = new Sprite(actorTexture);
```

Проинициализировать переменную color

```
Color color =new Color(Color.RED);
```

А потом в рендеренге

```
actorSprite.setColor(color);
```

Актер был синим стал зеленым

```
public class Laser extends BaseActor {
    Lasermid lasermid;
    Color color = new Color(Color.GREEN);

    public Laser(float x, float y, Stage s) {
        super(x, y, s);

        loadTexture("assets/Line11.png");

        setSize(30, 10);
        setMaxSpeed(800);
        setBoundaryPolygon(8);
        setSpeed(10);
        lasermid = new Lasermid(-30, 0, s);
        addActor(lasermid);
        lasermid.setColor(color);
        // lasermid.setPosition(getX(),getY());
    }

    public void act(float dt) {
        super.act(dt);
        applyPhysics(dt);
    }
}
```

Comment: Хм, а как этот получившийся спрайт дать актёру в качестве фона?

Comment: Это как общий пример его можно применить где угодно
public class Laser extends BaseActor {
    Lasermid lasermid;
Color color=new Color(Color.GREEN);

    public Laser(float x, float y, Stage s) {
        super(x, y, s);
        loadTexture("assets/Line11.png");
        setSize(30,10);
        setMaxSpeed(800);
        setBoundaryPolygon(8);
        setSpeed(10);
        lasermid=new Lasermid(-30,0,s);
        addActor(lasermid);
        lasermid.setColor(color);
      изначально актер был синим но я ему сказал быть зеленым

Comment: Начало объяснения: `Texture actorTexture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("actor.png")); Sprite  actorSprite  = new Sprite(actorTexture); Color   actorColor   = new Color(Color.RED); actorSprite.setColor(actorColor);` - мне понятно. Однако как всё-таки передать этот подготовленный спрайт `Actor`'у в качестве фона? А вот дальнейшее объяснение непонятно совершенно, потому что классы `BaseActor` и `Lasermid`, использованные в вашем примере, отсутствуют в "LibGDX".

Comment: Отредактируйте вопрос так чтоб был виден ваш код и в нем уже можно будет пояснить.

Comment: Пока что у меня нет никакого кода, так как я не знаю решения названной в вопросе проблемы.

Comment: Рекомендую вам почитать: Java Game
Development
with LibGDX
From Beginner to Professional
—
Second Edition
—
Lee Stemkoski